# Bass neck have a crack, following wood lines

Tags: electric-bass-guitar, guitar-neck

First a couple pictures:

[image]
[image]

I have a bass that has a crack on the neck. It looks like it follows the wood pattern, but since it's so clean, I think it's more glue related.
This happened after transport and, realistically, this bass has been used as a tool, and not a museum piece, for a long time so it's not like I'm totally surprised.

I am in a lockdown area, so there is no 'going to the music shop' right now.

I guess the truss rod, and maybe the fretboard, hold it together right now. I can push back against the crack and see it close, so it's definitely loose.

Does that mean I need to get a new neck? or can this eventually be glued by a repair shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is where a join in the neck was made. Were it mine, I'd open it up gently to see how much it's become unglued. Being careful not to crack the fingerboard. There were quite a few guitars and basses made this way, not sure it was a brilliant idea, but a lot survive!

Anyway, open up, and it should be possible to get two part epoxy into the joint, just enough not splodging it everywhere. Then using card or such, with some plastic bag over the joint, use clamps to hold it together for a day. Obviously take the strings off first!

If that's not something you'd be happy with, a luthier will be able to repair it - at a cost. A new neck would be an option - at a cost, but fitting won't be a simple diy job - the poket needs to be a snug fit. For me, the glue option would be the best, (I've done many broken necks) but it rather depends on how much of a diy-er you are!

Comment: I'll try the glue option, I have no problem hacking things around when needed :) I was wondering about the shape because I could imagine it to take more work to make two pieces that fit like that, and glue the, than doing a more straight shape

Comment: Thing is, the two parts (theoretically) were made for each other initially, so *should* fit back together with some epoxy resin. That's what I've used on all repairs like this. Without looking closely, I can't tell, but if it was really bad (don't think this is) I'd consider drilling a couple of small holes and putting screws in - each side of the trussrod, and filling over the heads, but that's in desperate case It ought to fit back quite well, if not, you'll be doing some sanding too...

Comment: I managed to get the glue, which was a bit complicated since we're in a lockdown area.. will experiment soon! I'm expecting some will come out and so I may have to sand the neck a bit.

Comment: Clamp it as tight as possible, in a big vice if you can, and scrape off the excess adhesive as it squeezes. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Also use masking tape all around the area of the crack so there's less to clean up. Maybe even lay it over the entire area and then cut the tape with a razor to expose the crack.